# natural numbers and successors

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I hope this question is not a repeat.

Given there is no $k \in N $ such that $ n < k < n+1 $ for $n \in N$

Prove for all $ m, n \in N $ if $ m < n $ then $ m+1 \leq n$

Conclude $ m < n $ implies $ m+1 < n + 1 $  and therefore $S(n) = n+1 $ defines a one - to - one function on $ N $.

NOTE $ N = \text{  natural numbers}$

Ok, this is what I have :

from the given, the first number greater than $n$ is $n+1$.

therefore if $m < n$ then $n \geq m+1 $

therefore $m+1 \leq n $

Is this correct?

I am not sure how to proceed with the second part, where I need to make the conclusions.

since $m < n$ I know from the proof that $ m + 1 \leq n$ and since $ n < n+1 $ then $ m + 1  < n + 1$

is this correct?

showing if S(n) is one to one:

assume $S(a) = S(b)$ for some $a, b \in N$
then $ a + 1 = b + 1 $
then $ a = b $
therefore $ S(n) $ is a one to one function.

Answer (score 1):

The first conclusion is almost immediate. Suppose, seeking a contradiction, that there were $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m< n$ but $m + 1 > n$. But that would mean that there was an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m < n < m+ 1$, a contradiction. So we must have $m < n \implies m+1 \leq n$. It immediately follows that $m+1 < n+1$, as you have shown.

To show it's injective, I would again use proof by contradiction. Suppose there were $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a+1 = b+1$, but $a \neq b$. Then, WLOG, assume $a<b$. But then we have $a+1 < b+1$, a contradiction by what we've just proved. So we're done.