# set of natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove each set of natural numbers is the set of all smaller natural numbers.
IE $ n =$ { $m \in N | m < n$ }

Hint: use induction to prove that all elements of a natural number are natural numbers.

The natural numbers are defined as : 0, 1, 2, ...etc.

The textbook I am using (Hrbacek and Jech) further defines:

$ 1 = \{ 0 \} = \{ \emptyset \}$

I am not sure if I am going about this correctly.

Step ONE: show it is true for the second smallest natural number 1

it is a given that $ 1 \in $ {$0$}

Step TWO: assume it is true for the natural number $k$
  IE: $k =$ { $m \in N | m< k$ }

Step THREE: prove it is true for natural number $ k + 1 $

since $ k = \{ m \in N | m < k \}$

and since $ k < k + 1$

then $m < k + 1 $

therefore $ k + 1 = \{ m \in N | m < k + 1 \}$

am I correct?

Comment: How have you had the natural numbers defined?

Comment: Erm. $1\in \left\{0\right\}$ is most likely false. You have $1=\left\{0\right\}$ so $0 \in 1$...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i just put in an edit now defining the natural numbers as 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: With that definition, there is no way to prove what you want to prove, unless you further define each of those symbols as some specific set.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft sorry I left out the definition that $1 = \{ 0 \} = \{ \emptyset \} $

Comment: That still does not provide enough to do this, until you also define the other natural numbers in some way.

Comment: To amplify Tobias's comment: There's a perfectly good set-theoretic representation of natural numbers, probably due to Zermelo, that makes $0=\varnothing$, $1=\{0\}$, $2=\{1\}$, $3=\{2\}$, etc.  For this definition, the result you're trying to prove is false. So you really do need the whole definitions of "natural number" (presumably using von Neumann's set-theoretic representation) and of "smaller". The details of these affect what can be assumed in your proof and what must be shown, so without those details answers can only be guesswork.

Comment: A more general comment: The result you're trying to prove is not "really" about natural numbers but about their set-theoretic representation. You learned how to handle natural numbers in elementary school (or earlier) and worked with them for years, with (I imagine) no inkling that each of them is the set of previous ones. Whenever you encounter a statement that, like this one, is "really" about a specific set-theoretic representation, you should expect to make use of the details of that representation in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you’ve actually defined $N$ to be the smallest set such that $0\in N$ and for all $n\in N$, $S(n)\in N$ or something very similar, and that you’ve defined $n+1$ to be $S(n)=n\cup\{n\}$ for $n\in N$. To show by induction that $n=\{k\in N:k<n\}$ for each $n\in N$, you must show two things:

1. $0=\{k\in N:k<0\}$, and
2. if $n\in N$ and $n=\{k\in N:k<n\}$, then $n+1=\{k\in N:k<n+1\}$.

Note that for (1) you want to start at $n=0$, not at $n=1$. (And what you have for $n=1$ isn’t correct: $1\notin 0$. In fact $1=0\cup\{0\}=\{0\}$, so $0\in 1$.) In order to prove (1) you must show that there is no $k\in N$ such that $k<0$. How you do this will depend on you you’ve defined the relation $<$; I don’t know your definition, so I can’t help here.

For (2), assume that $n=\{k\in N:k<n\}$. Then

$$n+1=S(n)=n\cup\{n\}=\{k\in N:k<n\}\cup\{n\}\;,$$

so to finish the induction step you must show that

$$\{k\in N:k<n\}\cup\{n\}=\{k\in N:k<n+1\}\;.$$

It’s very easy to see that

$$\{k\in N:k<n\}\cup\{n\}\subseteq\{k\in N:k<n+1\}\;,$$

so all that remains is to show that

$$\{k\in N:k<n+1\}\subseteq\{k\in N:k<n\}\cup\{n\}\;.$$

For this you’ll want the result from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401376/natural-numbers-and-successors).